# Display Online users in aws appsync based chat application

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have created a chat application using AWS Appsync. My problem is I am not able to identify online and offline users. I was thinking of marking user as active in database when they logged in, however i could not mark them as inactive because i am using single sign on and with no log out feature.

I verified the MQTT connection that subscription creates, but could not find anything relevant. Chat application is web application.

Answer (score 4):

One option you have here is to use [DynamoDB TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html).  You can write a record to a table to enable presence detection, and use a heartbeat mechanism to upsert these records from your application.  DynamoDB will handle deleting the records for you, so you do not need an explicit logout to mark them as inactive.

Comment: Please be aware that TTL deletions can take up to 48 hours after TTL deadline has been reached: 
From AWS documentation:
"Depending on the size and activity level of a table, the actual delete operation of an expired item can vary. Because TTL is meant to be a background process, the nature of the capacity used to expire and delete items via TTL is variable (but free of charge). TTL typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration."